# XY Grid - class="grid-container"

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation

I´m using the new XY-Grid from now on, but I´m not really clear about the class "grid-container".
The grid-container just marks the max-width of the Foundation-Grid, am I right?

For what case do I need the class "grid-container full"?
I do have the same output just without it. I mean, if I do it that way:

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="cell small-12">cell</div>
       Content
    </div
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The docs at https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#grid-container describe it a bit:

> The grid defaults to the full width of the available space. To contain it horizontally use the grid-container class. The container will be centered and have a max-width equal to your $grid-container setting (1200px by default), along with padding on the left/right equal to half your $grid-container-padding setting.

And the `full` class is also described at https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#grid-container-full:

> To stretch the content to the full width of the available space and remove grid container padding, simply add the class full to your grid-container. Note that this variation is primarily for use for the grid-margin-x - it works with grid-padding-x too, but will work the same as .grid-container.fluid.

The `full` class removes the padding from the grid container.

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.1/scss/xy-grid/_classes.scss#L21

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.1/scss/xy-grid/_grid.scss#L15

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.1/scss/xy-grid/_gutters.scss#L15

```
  // Grid Container
  .grid-container {
    @include xy-grid-container;

    &.full {
      @include xy-grid-container(100%, 0);
    }
  }

/// @param {Number} $width [$grid-container] - a width to limit the container to.
/// @param {Number} $padding [$grid-container-padding] - paddings of the container.
@mixin xy-grid-container(
  $width: $grid-container,
  $padding: $grid-container-padding
) {
  @include xy-gutters($gutters: $padding, $gutter-type: padding);
```

The following applies `padding-right: 0` and `padding-left: 0`:

```
/// Create gutters for a cell/container.
///
/// @param {Number|Map} $gutters [$grid-margin-gutters] - Map or single value for gutters.
/// @param {Keyword} $gutter-type [margin] - Type of gutter to output. Accepts either margin or padding.
/// @param {List} $gutter-position [right left] - The position to apply gutters to. Accepts `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` in any combination.
/// @param {Boolean} $negative [false] - Whether to apply the gutter as a negative value. Commonly used for nested grids.
@mixin xy-gutters(
  $gutters: $grid-margin-gutters,
  $gutter-type: margin,
  $gutter-position: right left,
  $negative: false
) {
  $operator: if($negative, '-', '');

  // If we have declared negative gutters, force type to `margin.
  $gutter-type: if($negative, 'margin', $gutter-type);

  // Output our margin gutters.
  @if (type-of($gutters) == 'map') {
    @include -zf-breakpoint-value(auto, $gutters) {
      $gutter: rem-calc($-zf-bp-value) / 2;

      // Loop through each gutter position
      @each $value in $gutter-position {
        #{$gutter-type}-#{$value}: unquote("#{$operator}#{$gutter}");
      }
    }
  }
  @else if (type-of($gutters) == 'number') {
    $gutter: rem-calc($gutters) / 2;

    // Loop through each gutter position
    @each $value in $gutter-position {
      #{$gutter-type}-#{$value}: unquote("#{$operator}#{$gutter}");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks...

But how do I nest grids?

In older versions you started with row, then columns, then row and then columns.
Do I have to add a grid column in every cell?

Comment: Exactly, with XY Grid, row => grid-x, column => cell. You can still nest. See https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#grid-frame

Comment: Ok, but the grid-frame is a little bit large for this action?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The grid-frame clss is just for specific use cases. Nesting is generally possible.

Comment: Ok - but when do I have to use the grid-container.

For example I build something like this:

    grid-container -> grid-x -> cell

Let´s say now I want another grid, nested in the cell - do I have to start a new grid-container or is it enough to work with grid-x?

The main-question is, do I use the grid-container more than once on one site?
Maybe you have an example site!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You do not necessarily need the grid-container class but you can try and see yourself what it does.

Comment: The grid-container class basically just applies a max-width, see https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.1/scss/xy-grid/_grid.scss#L9.